# Using a hook to retrieve a context imported from an imported module returns undefined

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-context

Happy Friday.

Let me see if I can lay out the problem clearly here:

I build up a bunch of providers in a 'core' package `project-core` to be shared across a bunch of related projects, and wrap them all in a super provider `ProjAppProvider`, which I then wrap around my related project, call it `Proj1`.

So, super simplified to make the issue clear, let's just use material-ui's `ThemeProvider` as an example (but, in reality, I have apollo-client, notistack, an auth provider, etc.):

In core...

```
import * as React from 'react'
import theme from '../theme'
import {ThemeProvider} from '@material-ui/core'

const ProjAppProvider = ({children}) => {
  return(
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
    {children}
    <ThemeProvider>
  }
}
export default ProjAppProvider
```

and then export that in the index and publish that package.

Then in project-one's package.json I import project-core and then do something like this:

```
import...
import ProjAppProvider from 'project-core'

const WrappedApp = () => {
  return (
    <ProjAppProvider>
      <ProjOneComponent />
    </ProjAppProvider>
  )
}
```

and then in `ProjOneComponent`:

```
...
import {useTheme} from '@material-ui/core'

const ProjOneComponent = () => {
  const theme = useTheme()
  console.log(theme)
}
```

I get the default theme. If this were notistack, I'd get `undefined`. Just happens that MUI has a fallback.

Some provisos to stick on here... if at any point in project-core, I use that hook (inside the provider), it works as expected. Also, it appears that if I actually **export** the hook itself from project-core and use that (i.e., projUseTheme is just exported useTheme), it works.

Everything else "works". It's definitely seeing the core package, importing the right version, etc. etc. Shared components work as expected. Same versions of @material-ui/notistack in both. The theme is available anywhere in the core package-- meaning in nested providers, I can read it correctly. It's something about importing a provider, wrapping it, and then using the `use...` hook from the original package to retrieve the context that isn't working (or, more likely, I'm not understanding.)

Also, it appears, though I haven't had the time to bisect it, that this started when we upgraded to React 17 and/or CRA 4. Not sure about that. I'll be working on that debugging when I get time.

Any input on what to look for, and/or, if I'm just missing something about why this would be expected is appreciated.

*Update:*
Seems that I have to export the useTheme and makeStyles from the core package, and that'll make it work. (I.e., `import useTheme as coreUseTheme from '@mui'` and then `export const coreUseTheme` in core... and `import {coreUseTheme as useTheme}` in project-one.

The issue seems to be that the two referencing and external provider conflict somehow? Even if I get the theme from coreUseTheme and log it, it's right. But *if I don't import makeStyles from core, and pass it that theme, it will just ignore it and use the default*. Which... kinda blows my mind if I'm being really honest.

Comment: My guess would be that the dependencies (such as Material-UI) are being pulled in twice -- by both project-core and your app. This would result in two different types for each context being used. I would recommend declaring packages such as Material-UI to be peer-dependencies in project-core.

Comment: That turned out to be the right answer. I don't fully understand why that happens under the hood, but by making mui and others peer dependencies in core and then installing them in each of the projects, the problem went away.